# Angular 7 - How to capture 500 server error on http.post when returning a new Promise?

Tags: angular, promise, http-post

I'm getting a 500 server error (which I expect) but my current implementation does not capture the error. Instead of capturing the error in the component and handling it, the app produces a 500 server error in the browser console and the execution gets halted and the loading spinner remains. I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I've restructured the promise a few different ways with no luck.

** Update **

I updated the service to use reject in the promise but that still did not work.

Component code

```
save() {
    this.loading = true;  this.itemService.updateItems(this.updatedItems, this.activeCompanyId).then(() => {
       this.loading = false;
     }).catch((err) => {
       console.log("Error updating items", err);
     });
  }
```

Service code

```
updateItems(items:Item[], companyId) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .set("CompanyId", companyId);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(`${this._config.API_URL}`, items, { headers }).subscribe(
        data => {
          resolve(data);
        },
        err => {
          console.log('Error updating items', err);
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Just a question, there is a reason that you use Promises instead of working with Observables that are natively used in Angular ?

Comment: No particular reason other than then using what I already knew. I'm more than happy to re-factor to use an Observable instead just not sure how to do it properly. Originally when I chose to use Promises I went with what at the time I felt was the safer option for the requests to behave as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

In case of an error, you want to reject the Promise:

```
updateItems(items:Item[], companyId) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .set("CompanyId", companyId);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(`${this._config.API_URL}`, items, { headers }).subscribe(
        data => {
          resolve(data);
        },
        err => {
          console.log('Error updating items', err);
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work :( I updated the question to reflect the usage of reject in the promise. Nothing gets logged out except the 500 server error in the browser console and the spinner remains.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your issue might be the http interceptor: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

create a file (for example error-interceptor.ts and inside add the following (be sure to add this class to your module's providers)

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor() {}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        catchError((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {              
            console.error(errorResponse.error);             
        })
    );
}
```

}

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true }
],
```

As the name implies, you can now "intercept" all incoming http responses and check for an error.  Depending on what you're using to send back your response on the backside, your response after an error (this is express).

```
res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Boo-Boo" });
```

Then you can access the message with:

```
errorResponse.error.message;
```

Comment: The HttpInterceptor will catch every response, it's not the question here.

Comment: It will only catch all of them if you want it to.  They can easily be filtered based on response code, message or anything else.

Comment: I already had an interceptor in place for authentication so I filtered it based on response code 500

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using an HttpIntercepter

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, of, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public navService: NavService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let request = req.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });

    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError((err, caught) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 500) {
          return throwError(err)
        }
      }
      return of(err);
    }) as any);
  }
}
```